# How can I make magicline animation with horizontal scrollable navigation?

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is the code I've ever write. If there is no scrolling, it works correctly. But when you click the remaining elements in the scrolling area does not work properly. Click on the elements after Link4 to understand the problem.

```js
$(function() {
  $(".li").click(function() {
    $(".magicline").css({
      width:
        $(this)
          .outerWidth() + "px",
      left:
        $(this)
          .position().left + "px"
    });
  });
  
  $(".li").first().trigger("click");
});
```

```css
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

ul,
li {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.nav {
  width: 300px;
  display: flex;
  border-top: 1px solid tomato;
  border-bottom: 1px solid tomato;
  margin-top: 100px;
  overflow: auto;
  position: relative;
}

.li {
  white-space: nowrap;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.item {
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #444;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
}

.magicline {
  position: absolute;
  /* width js, left js */
  position: absolute;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 25px;
  background-color: pink;
  transition: 0.3s;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

```html
<ul class="nav">
  <div class="magicline"></div>
  <li class="li"><a href="#0" class="item">Link 1</a></li>
  <li class="li"><a href="#0" class="item">Link 2</a></li>
  <li class="li"><a href="#0" class="item">Link 3</a></li>
  <li class="li"><a href="#0" class="item">Link 4</a></li>
  <li class="li"><a href="#0" class="item">Link 5</a></li>
  <li class="li"><a href="#0" class="item">Link 6</a></li>
  <li class="li"><a href="#0" class="item">Link 7</a></li>
  <li class="li"><a href="#0" class="item">Link 8</a></li>
  <li class="li"><a href="#0" class="item">Link 9</a></li>
</ul>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add the `scrollLeft` property of the parent:

```js
$(function() {
  $(".li").click(function() {
    var lft = $(this).parent().scrollLeft() + $(this).position().left; // <---
    $(".magicline").css({
      width:
        $(this)
          .outerWidth() + "px",
      left:
        lft + "px"
    });
  });
  
  $(".li").first().trigger("click");
});
```

```css
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

ul,
li {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.nav {
  width: 300px;
  display: flex;
  border-top: 1px solid tomato;
  border-bottom: 1px solid tomato;
  margin-top: 100px;
  overflow: auto;
  position: relative;
}

.li {
  white-space: nowrap;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.item {
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #444;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
}

.magicline {
  position: absolute;
  /* width js, left js */
  position: absolute;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 25px;
  background-color: pink;
  transition: 0.3s;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

```html
<ul class="nav">
  <div class="magicline"></div>
  <li class="li"><a href="#0" class="item">Link 1</a></li>
  <li class="li"><a href="#0" class="item">Link 2</a></li>
  <li class="li"><a href="#0" class="item">Link 3</a></li>
  <li class="li"><a href="#0" class="item">Link 4</a></li>
  <li class="li"><a href="#0" class="item">Link 5</a></li>
  <li class="li"><a href="#0" class="item">Link 6</a></li>
  <li class="li"><a href="#0" class="item">Link 7</a></li>
  <li class="li"><a href="#0" class="item">Link 8</a></li>
  <li class="li"><a href="#0" class="item">Link 9</a></li>
</ul>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
```